# Errors with strcat

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcat

The following is part of my code. The code finds groups of items with the same value in array listL. Only main() should be needed to understand I hope.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void append(char* s, char c)
{
        int len = strlen(s);
        s[len] = c;
        s[len+1] = '\0';
}

int leftSame(int listL[4][4][2], int i, int j){
    if(j==0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(listL[i][j][0]==listL[i][j-1][0]){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;

}

int topSame(int listL[4][4][2], int i, int j){
    if(i==0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(listL[i][j][0]==listL[i-1][j][0]){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;

}
int realIndex(char group[64][256],int a){
    while (strlen(group[a])<3){
        a = atoi(group[a]);
    }
    return a;
}
int main(void)
{
    int listL[4][4][2]= {{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}},{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}},{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}},{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}}};
    char group[64][256];
    int count = 0;
    size_t i,j;
    char snum[256];
    int leftIndex=0;
    int topIndex=0;
    int a=0;
    int A=0;
    int B=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++){
        memset(group[i], 0, 256 + 1);// zero all memory in the list
    }

    for(i=0;i<sizeof(listL)/sizeof(listL[0]);i++){
        for(j=0;j<sizeof(listL)/sizeof(listL[0]);j++){
            A= leftSame(listL,i,j);
            B=topSame(listL,i,j);
            if(A && B){
                leftIndex=realIndex(group,listL[i][j-1][1]);
                topIndex=realIndex(group,listL[i-1][j][1]);
                if (topIndex==leftIndex){
                    sprintf(snum, "%d", i);
                    strcat(group[leftIndex],snum);
                    strcat(group[leftIndex],'_');
                    sprintf(snum, "%d", j);
                    strcat(group[leftIndex],snum);
                    strcat(group[leftIndex],'_');
                    listL[i][j][1]=leftIndex;
                }
            }
        }

    }
        return 0;




}
```

I'm getting errors "passing argument 2 of ‘strcat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast" for each use of strcat. Isn't cast accounted for when I defined snum as sum[256]? What does it mean and how do I fix it?

What I'm trying to do is append the string "i_j_" to the item in group[leftIndex].

Comment: '_' is a character, not a string/character array.

Comment: the posted code fails to compile for several reasons.  Suggest enabiling all compiler warnings.   Amongst many other things, '#include <stdio.h>' is missing, so sprintf() is not defined, so default (all int) parameters are expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass character literals (wrapped in `'`) as the second argument to some of the `strcat`s like

```
strcat(group[leftIndex],'_');
```

but `strcat` expects the second argument (as well as its first argument) to be of type `char*`, not `char` and both of them needs to be NUL-terminated. This is why the complainer is complaining.

Use a string literal instead of a character literal to fix the problem:

```
strcat(group[leftIndex],"_");
```

---

```
memset(group[i], 0, 256 + 1);
```

has an off by one error. Use

```
memset(group[i], 0, 256);
```

or better

```
memset(group[i], 0, sizeof(group[i]))
```

Comment: Also, it seems that `group` is never initialized.

Comment: @iharob , `memset(group[i], 0, 256 + 1)`? Although it is supposed to be `memset(group[i], 0, 256)` or better `memset(group[i], 0, sizeof(group[i])`

Comment: Hey that did it! Thanks, I'm still used to python where it doesn't matter I guess.

Comment: @CoolGuy I don't get it, what's wrong with group? It runs fine... This is my first proper c program so please keep it simple.

Comment: @user2998454 , Are you asking about the `memset`? If so, it is because `group[i]` consist of 256 slots. You set `0` in 256+1 slots, Thus, the last 0 is written in an invalid memory location invoking Undefined Behavior as you write to locations not owned by you.

Comment: @CoolGuy yes I missed that, but it actually would be enough like `group[i][0] = '\0'`.

Comment: @iharob, this line: 'group[i][0] = '\0';' would only set a single entry.  so memset() would be the right method to use.

Comment: @user3629249 I know that, it's just that the original code had `malloc(1)`, so `memcpy(x, y, 1);` is not different.

Answer (score 0):

Strongly suggest compiling with all warnings enabled.

For gcc use

```
'-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'
```

as a minumum

```
remember that code formatting/style is for human readability
so use white space, both vertically around code blocks
and horizontally between 'tokens'
```

here is a modified list of the main() function, that cleanly compiles

Plus the missing header file:

```
#include <stdio.h> // sprintf()

int main(void)
{
    int listL[4][4][2]= {{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}},{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}},{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}},{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}}};
    char group[64][256];
    //int count = 0;
    size_t i,j;
    char snum[256];
    int leftIndex=0;
    int topIndex=0;
    //int a=0;
    int A=0;
    int B=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++){
        memset(group[i], 0, 256 + 1);// zero all memory in the list
    }

    for(i=0; i<sizeof(listL)/sizeof(listL[0]); i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<sizeof(listL)/sizeof(listL[0]); j++)
        {
            A= leftSame( listL, i, j );
            B= topSame(  listL, i, j );

            if(A && B)
            {
                leftIndex = realIndex( group, listL[i][j-1][1] );
                topIndex  = realIndex( group, listL[i-1][j][1] );

                if (topIndex == leftIndex)
                {
                    //sprintf(snum, "%d", i);
                    sprintf( snum, "%u", (unsigned)i );

                    strcat( group[leftIndex], snum );
                    //strcat(group[leftIndex],'_');
                    strcat( group[leftIndex],"_" );

                    //sprintf(snum, "%d", j);
                    sprintf( snum, "%u", (unsigned)j );

                    strcat( group[leftIndex], snum );

                    //strcat(group[leftIndex],'_');
                    strcat( group[leftIndex], "_" );

                    listL[i][j][1] = leftIndex;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```